# Button from parentVIewController still display on screen after pushViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am a newbie at IOS, and I get stuck in this weird problem
it's really an easy demo, I just want jump to another viewController.

```
//parentViewController
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Search Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){
    print("Button tapped")
    let searchVC = MfSearchViewController()
    self.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

and this is the target viewController

```
class MfSearchViewController:UIViewController{
    /// UI component
    var tableView:UITableView!
    var searchBar:UISearchBar!
    var searchLabel:UILabel!
    ///
    var dataSource = NSMutableArray()
    var currentIndexPaht: NSIndexPath?
    var screenObj = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for index in 0...12{
            let model = SearchResultModel(searchWord: "java\(index+1)", searchResult: "1500")
            dataSource.addObject(model)
        }
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        //tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0,20,screenObj.width,screenObj.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.title = "target"


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension MfSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier: String = "SearchResultCellIdentifier"
        // may be no value, so use optional
        var cell: SearchResultCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? SearchResultCell
        if cell == nil { // no value
            cell = SearchResultCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
        let model: SearchResultModel? = dataSource[indexPath.row] as? SearchResultModel
        cell!.configureCell(model)
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

   }

extension MfSearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(indexPath);
    }

}
```

but after pushViewcontroller, button from parentViewController still there...plz help me....many thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a subview to a UINavigationController's view. Doing so will cause the view to appear on all subsequent screens of its view controllers. It is generally not necessary to add views to UINavigationController's view. Rather you should create view controllers that are dynamically pushed and popped onto the navigation controller's stack. That is, create a root view controller with button that calls an action that performs:

```
let searchVC = MfSearchViewController()
self.navigationController.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: true)
```

Causing the view with the button transition off while the new view transitions on. Simply calling `button.removeFromSuperView()` will cause the button to disappear but will be very abrupt and will not conform to iOS user experience or design pattern.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for your help, I really need more reading and study:)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with UIViewControllers and storyboards but for now you could just remove the button before changing viewControllers.

```
 button.removeFromSuperView()
```

you have to make the button a global property so you can call it outside of ViewDidLoad where it was created.
I am not sure if this is expected behaviour or if the button should be removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know you get answer but maybe i can spot some tricks about transition between views.

```
self.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: true)
```

"self" means that you are in `UIViewController` object and `UIViewController` gonna push it. So, for example if you push class B from A, in B class you will not able to root anything under control of navigation stack. Also you are not in `UINavigationController` stack.

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: true)
```

Now you are using your `UIViewController` objects `UINavigationController` and able to handle your navigation stack on class B. This is the true way to push, present or handle every transition between `UIView` objects.